# Docker Compose node_modules in container empty after file change

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a Node.js in a Docker container via Docker Compose.
The `node_modules` should be created in the image and the source code should be synced from the host.

Therefore, I use 2 volumes in docker-compose.yml. One for my project source and other for the `node_modules` in the image.

Everything seems to be working. The `node_modules` are installed and `nodemon` starts the app. In my docker container I have a `node_modules` folder with all dependencies. On my host an empty `node_modules` is created (I am not sure if this is expected).

But, when I change a file from the project. The `nodemon` process detects a file change and restarts the app. Now the app crashes because it can't find modules. The `node_modules` folder in the Docker container is empty now.

What am I doing wrong?

My folder structure looks like this

```
/
├── docker-compose.yml
├── project/
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./project
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/app/
      - /app/node_modules/
```

project/Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:9

ENV APP_ROOT /app

# set working directory
RUN mkdir $APP_ROOT
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json $APP_ROOT
COPY package-lock.json $APP_ROOT
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . $APP_ROOT

# start app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

project/package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
}
...
```

Comment: Since you are talking about nodemon, I guess you want a development setup and not production?

Comment: Yes it's for a development setup.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping a volume works to make files available to the container, not the other way round.

You can fix your issue by running "npm install" as part of the CMD. You can achieve this by having a "startup" script (eg start.sh) that runs npm install && npm run start. The script should be copied in the container with a normal COPY command and be executable.

When you start your container you should see files in the node_modules folder (on host).

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of these two solutions :

- `npm install` on the host and make a volume that the container can use and that references the host `node_modules` folder.
- Use `npm install` in the image/container build process - which can be a pain for a  development setup since it will `npm i` everytime you restart the container (if you change some files).